# Add a scroll in a form on Access 2013

Tags: ms-access

Is there some way to add a scrolling bar in the part of the labels 1,2 and 3? Cause I'll need to add a lots of labels with their respective text:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lD2nN.png)

Thanks

Comment: Labels cannot scroll. A _ListBox_ can, a _ComboBox_ can drop down, and a _TextBox_ can have multiple lines. You may have to explain your need.

Comment: I wanted a little scroll bar in the part where I have 1,2 and 3 labels just in that part in that rectangle, but that seems not to be possible, instead I can clearly use the normal scroll bar, may be a solution but not I as wanted

Comment: A subform may do what you want - put your labels/text boxes in the subform, then the subform on the main form with the size you want it to have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supposed that you have changed you database to use "Overlapping Documents", set the ***AutoResize*** property of the form to ***No*** and size the window manually. By default, Access will add a scrollbar to the details section if needed.

To achive this, add the fields that should not be scrollable to the form header of footer, and make sure that there's enough room to display the header and footer of the form. "Save" the form when done with resizing (Ctrl+S).

Example:

[image: scrollable Details section]

When using the "Tabbed Documents" layout, you could for example make the footer of the form very high to force the scrollbar to appear, but that scrollbar will appear at the very right border of the Access window.